# Iframe exceeds a div in a parent web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am embedding an video in a parent website where the iframe is a bit longer than the div.

PLease refer to the image below:[image]

If we consider the iframe as the filled portion, and div as the non filled portion, we can see that the iframe is exceeded the div and also the iframe outside the div is not even visible. Can any one suggest a iframe css change so that i can apply to it? I cant change the div as it is not controlled by me (a third paty website to embed my videos) and also i can not apply javascript to the iframe for the same reason. I just can apply css to adjust the size of the iframe.

iframe code below:

```
<iframe style="width: 500px; height: 100%;" title="test" src="/my/src/video" ></iframe>
```

i have tried to change the width:100%, but the issue exists. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Can you please provide the URL to where this lives.

Comment: @SleekGeek Sorry. I cant provide the url where it resides as we need login credentials . Can you please suggest in anyother way please based on my explanation?

Comment: Since the width if fixed, try setting the Iframe's max-width to 100% and be sure that the position of the parent element is set to "relative

Comment: Tried width: 400px?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<iframe width="100%" style="height: 100%" title="test" src="/my/src/video" >  </iframe>
```

Comment: width for iframe as attribute is not allowing. As is said i have no control over the parent site and it was automatically removing the width attribute. @David

Comment: Then you are left with trying max-width or a smaller width value. Owners of an iframe have (thankfully) very limited control over how it'll look embedded. Might not be possible for you, but this problem should be solved by whomever controls the parent page

Comment: I have tried max-width:100% but unfortunately , it didnt worked. :( Can you please let me know if i can control the size of iframe using css? @David